# How to make buttons within a div not get clicked by accident if the user clicks around them?

Tags: javascript, css, button, click

```js
const btns =  document.querySelector('#btns')
btns.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    console.log('Hello')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="btns">

            <button id="btn1">btn</button>
            <button id="btn2">btn</button>
            <button id="btn3">btn</button>
            <button id="btn4">btn</button>

        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have 4 buttons inside a div. Each one does a different thing if clicked. The problem is that the afferent code of the button does execute even if the user clicks around and between the buttons. I know I would be able to solve the problem within the javascript code by creating an if statement and telling the button to do something only when the value will be the one defined. I would like to know if there is an easy solution for this with css.

```html
<div id="choices">
  <button type="button" class="btns" id="btn1">?</button>
  <button type="button" class="btns" id="btn2">?</button>
  <button type="button" class="btns" id="btn3">?</button>
  <button type="button" class="btns" id="btn4">?</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow. As it is, that code would likely render 4 buttons in a row with no gaps between them.

Comment: Seems to be related to the display mode you are using for the buttons. Default display mode is inline-block. Ad @HereticMonkey said, maybe with the elements CSS we cana figure out the actual issue.

Comment: The snippet has been added to the post.

Comment: I know you may say that i m telling the event listener to execute the code when it's pressed inside of the div, but if the buttons are targeted as individuals and they are told to do certain things when only one of the buttons will be clicked they will do different things even if clicked inside of the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know a lot about the java script but i can help you

do an if condition that says

```
if (mouseY>"the point of y in south of the button "
&mouseY<"the point of y  in north of the button+its height "&
mouseX>"the point of x in west of the button"&
mouseX<"the point of x  in east of the button+its width "&mousePressed){execute}
```

don't copy the code because it is for **java processing** but under stand it's idea 
the idea is to make your button border